# Git alias for re-merging with the lastest from master

Tags: git, fish

I've spent a fair amount of time over the past few days on SO reading through threads but still haven't found a decent answer for this.

If I'm working in a feature branch and after a few days I want to pull in the latest changes from master I run the command:

```
git stash; and git checkout master; and git pull origin master; and git checkout <FEATURE BRANCH>; and git merge master; and git stash apply;
```

If that looks a little off it's because I use Fish and not Bash. Just replace all the `; and` with `&&` to get it to work in Bash.

Anyways, I'd like a git alias called "remaster" that automatically does this for me so that when I type `git remaster` it fires of all those commands. The biggest challenge is getting the feature branch's name and saving it for use later in the sequence when we re-check it out.

Anyone have any way to do this or any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `git fetch` and merge remote changes to your branch with `git merge origin/master`.

That alias works in `bash`, so you probably wanna port it to a `fish`:

```
[alias]
    remaster = "!f() { git stash && git fetch origin && git merge origin/master && git stash apply; }; f"
```

But anyway, current branch name could be retrieved via `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`.

Answer (score 3):

You can reduce the number of commands by merging with origin/master, like so:

```
git stash
git fetch origin
git merge origin/master
git stash pop
```

You can make a macro based on this:

```
[alias]
remaster = "!f() { git stash && git fetch origin && git merge origin/master && git stash pop }; f"
```